# Coaxial cable identification

Tags: coaxial-cable

Is there a way to identify this coaxial cable? I am interested in model and parameters such as epsilon, diameters etc. There is nothing written.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [Sucoform 141](https://dev-ecatalog.hubersuhner.com/product/ecatalog/Radio-frequency/Cables/22511925/SUCOFORM-141) or a clone. A semi-rigid coax with PTFE insulation, 71% velocity factor.

It's useable up to 33 GHz, though the SMA connectors won't go so high. Loss is about the same as RG-58. Power handling is pretty high.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share how you identified it, though I appreciate that it might just be from experience. :)

Comment: Experience. It's a pretty common cable, and one of the best for lab/instrument use. It comes in various sizes but the SMA connectors give it scale. In fact the connectors often are just a two-part shell for the outer, the pin is just the inner conductor sticking out, sharpened to remove any burr.

Comment: @David Hoelzer, cool, thanks a lot :)